# SQL Select inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

tengo este problema de que según yo hice un query para obtener una sola una fila de respuesta, pero por alguna razón obtengo varias veces el mismo registro, alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
select
  [Nombre de Obra],
  Estado =
  case estatus
when '0'
then 'Falta número de registro por el IMSS'
when '1'
then CONVERT(varchar(10), ob.[Número de registro de obra])
end,

ob.[Registro Patronal DV], [Nombre, denomicacion o razon social] patron,
  ob.RFC,

  concat(
    calle + ' ', [numero exterior] + ' ', [numero interior] + ' ',
    colonia + ' ',
    municipiodelegacion + ' /',
    codigopostal + ' ',
    localidad + ' /',
    entidadfederativa
  ) Ubicación

  , st2.[Herramienta y equipo], st2.[Costo directo del análisis de precios unitarios], st2.[Costos indirectos, utilidad y financiamiento], st2.[Días pagados], st2.[Importe presupuestado(sin IVA)], st2.[Mano de obra], st2.Materiales


from ObrasSatic ob
inner join saticF2 st2
on st2.[Número de registro de obra] = ob.[Número de registro de obra]
where ob.id_obra = 2
```

Comment: Seguramente tienes varios registros en la tabla con la que estas haciendo el Join ya que recuerda que te va a mostrar tantos registros coincidan con el número de registro de obra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver usando **SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement**
Algo así (obviamente agregando los join y todo lo necesario para tu caso):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Nombre de Obra] FROM ObrasSatic.
```

Para mas info sobre "DISTINCT"  [click aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Espero que te ayude. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si es como lo estoy imaginando, te falta poner la instrucciòn "GROUP BY", para que te agrupe los registros cuando sean iguales, intenta agruparlos por el nombre de la obra o por el estado.

Algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT * FROM ObrasSatic WHERE id_obra = 2 GROUP BY Nombre de Obra
```

y con eso solo te deberìa mostrar una fila.